# Kotlin - Error Capturing Image From camera on JAVA code its OK

Tags: android, camera, kotlin, android-camera-intent

This is my JAVA Code Converted to Kotlin.
after conversion the code gives me some error, on java its working perfectly without any errors. 
After taking image from camera the error is thrown .
what causes the issue ??

I am using ['com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.1-native'](https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop) library for cropping the image

```
    private fun dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(baseContext.packageManager) != null) {
        var photoFile: File? = null
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile()
        } catch (ex: IOException) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
        }

        if (photoFile != null) {
            try {
                photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(baseContext,
                        "com.anvinsolutions.akhil.pravda.fileprovider",
                        photoFile)
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), photoURI.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

        }
    }
}
    private fun dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(baseContext.packageManager) != null) {
        var photoFile: File? = null
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile()
        } catch (ex: IOException) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
        }

        if (photoFile != null) {
            try {
                photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(baseContext,
                        "com.anvinsolutions.akhil.pravda.fileprovider",
                        photoFile)
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), photoURI.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

        }
    }
}

@Throws(IOException::class)
private fun createImageFile(): File {
    // Create an image file name
    val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), timeStamp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    val imageFileName = "JPEG_$timeStamp"
    val storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
    val image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName, /* prefix */
            ".jpg", /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    )

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.absolutePath
    Log.e("PATH ==> ",mCurrentPhotoPath)
    return image
}

/*********************************** CAMERA  */


private fun startCropActivity(uri: Uri) {
    //Log.e("","wfwefwefwef")
    var destinationFileName = "Akhil"
    destinationFileName += ".jpg"
    val uCrop = UCrop.of(uri, Uri.fromFile(File(cacheDir, destinationFileName)))
    val options = UCrop.Options()
    //options.withAspectRatio(3,4);
    options.setFreeStyleCropEnabled(true)
    //options.withMaxResultSize(396,512);
    options.setHideBottomControls(true)
    options.setCompressionFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG)
    uCrop.withOptions(options)
    uCrop.start(this@member_form)
}

private fun pickFromGallery() {
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.type = "image/*"
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select one"), REQUEST_SELECT_PICTURE)
}


private fun handleCropResult(result: Intent) {
    croppedImage = UCrop.getOutput(result)!!
    if (croppedImage != null) {
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "OK CROP COMPLETED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        take_photo.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent)
        take_photo.setImageURI(croppedImage)
        /*ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = take_photo.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = 396;
        layoutParams.height = 512;
        take_photo.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);*/
        take_photo.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER
        take_photo.adjustViewBounds = true
        //ResultActivity.startWithUri(SampleActivity.this, croppedImage);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

private fun handleCropError(result: Intent) {
    val cropError = UCrop.getError(result)
    if (cropError != null) {
        Log.e("Error: ", "handleCropError: ", cropError)
        Toast.makeText(baseContext, cropError.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Unexpected Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}


public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
    Log.e("Result", "RequestCode=$requestCode Result Code=$resultCode")

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            startCropActivity(photoURI!!)
            Log.e("","startCropActivity")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }else{
        Log.e("Result"," : NOT OK")
    }

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_PICTURE) {
            val selectedUri = data.data
            if (selectedUri != null) {
                startCropActivity(data.data!!)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        } else if (requestCode == UCrop.REQUEST_CROP) {
            handleCropResult(data)
        }
    }
    if (resultCode == UCrop.RESULT_ERROR) {
        handleCropError(data)
        Log.e("", "CROP RESULT ERROR")
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, null)
}
```

This is the error message,

```
 Process: com.anvinsolutions.akhil.pravda, PID: 14120
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.anvinsolutions.akhil.pravda/com.anvinsolutions.akhil.pravda.member_form}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter data
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3738)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3781)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:153)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1424)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5523)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter data
    at com.anvinsolutions.akhil.pravda.member_form.onActivityResult(member_form.kt)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6508)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null:
```

hardly to say which one exactly is null. For instance

```
public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
```

the Intent could be null, and it should be marked as nullabe. Change it with

```
public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
```

Comment: You are Absolutely correct bro.. i thought  the  photoURI is causing the problem. :P you made it! :D and i have one doubt in this case on kotlin  what happens if the data is null ?? kotlin avoids null pointer exceptions. what is actually causing the issue here?

Comment: use `?.` before accessing the object

Comment: yeah bro i have done it and it doesn't have any problem now :) let me know what is the exact issue? :P beginner in kotlin!

Comment: I am also facing the issue and I am wondering how the data is becoming null, we are setting the photoURI and passing it on

Comment: @anoop4real it is hard to say without seeing the code

Comment: @Blackbelt its the same code "takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)" you are sending the photoURI as extra which should come as part of data right? I am following https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics and trying to do in Kotlin

Comment: if you set the same intent as setResult, yes you should get a no-null-intent back